# Touch issues with Pi4 and touchscreen

Tags: raspbian, touchscreen

I'm just developing a software with react that is supposed to run on a Pi and is interacted by a touchscreen. The only problem is that the touchscreen is not working as intended. Sometimes it won't release the touch so that the element you clicked on is focused. Also the touchscreen has a significant delay when swiping over the screen. I tested this behaviour with tecagile.com. All in all, the touch behavoiur is pretty bad and not working properly as I wish.

I'm using a Pi4B with Taspbian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye) and a hannspree HT225 21,5" touchscreen.

Can anyone help me or knows steps that I can do to fix the problem?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.